# Date Picker doesn't work with a new version of angular-ui-bootstrap 2.2.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, uidatepicker

I will try to explain my confusions. So I'm working with angular ui bootstrap tools and angular ui grid. In my grid I have a columns with a date picker. With angular-ui-bootstrap 1.3.3 my date picker works great but with angular-ui-bootstrap 2.2.0 I cannot see my date picker at all. It looks like it has been loaded but for some reason it is hidden. I went thru docs and change log and didn't find any things that have been done on the UI side. I need to use lib 2.2.0 because it critical for other ui elements in my app, such as modals and uib-accordion. And this is my question, What am I missing and Do you I need to use some specific a "new" tag for a latest library ?

This is [plunker with example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0w7oAggajWWj3Dc0j8B?p=preview). To see my misunderstandings you just need to comment lib 1.3.3 and uncomment lib 2.2.0. I appreciate any help.

Code for custom directive:

```
     $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    },
    columnDefs: [
      {
        field: 'DATE_TIME',
        displayName: 'Date Time',
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCellEdit: false,
        filterHeaderTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-filter-container row"><div ng-repeat="colFilter in col.filters" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-0"><div custom-grid-date-filter-header></div></div></div>',
        filters: [
          {
            name: 'From',
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL
          },
          {
            name: 'To',
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL
          }
        ],
        cellFilter: 'date:"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"',
        width: '40%'
      },
      {
        field: 'QTY',
        displayName: 'Quantity',
        enableCellEdit: false,
        enableFiltering: false
      },
      {
        field: 'UNIT_COST',
        displayName: 'Unit Cost',
        enableCellEdit: false,
        enableFiltering: false
      },
      {
        field: 'TOTAL_COST',
        displayName: 'Total Cost',
        enableCellEdit: false,
        enableFiltering: false
      }
    ]
  };

  $http.get('grid-data.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
      _.forEach($scope.gridOptions.data, function (val) {
          val.DATE_TIME = new Date(val.DATE_TIME);
      });
    });
}])

.controller('gridDatePickerFilterCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$uibModal', 'uiGridConstants', function( $scope, $timeout, $uibModal, uiGridConstants) {

  $timeout(function() {
    console.log($scope.col); 
    var field = $scope.col.colDef.name;

    var allDates = _.map($scope.col.grid.appScope.gridOptions.data, function(datum) {
      return datum[field];
    });

    var minDate = _.min(allDates);
    var maxDate = _.max(allDates);

    $scope.openDatePicker = function(filter) {

      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'custom-date-filter.html',
        controller: 'customGridDateFilterModalCtrl as custom',
        size: 'md',
        windowClass: 'custom-date-filter-modal',
        resolve: {
          filterName: [function() {
            return filter.name;
          }],
          minDate: [function() {
            return new Date(minDate);
          }],
          maxDate: [function() {
            return new Date(maxDate);
          }],
        }
      });

      modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedDate) {

        console.log('date', selectedDate);
        $scope.colFilter.listTerm = [];

        console.log(typeof selectedDate);
        console.log(selectedDate instanceof Date);

        $scope.colFilter.term = selectedDate;
      });
    };

  });


}])
.controller('customGridDateFilterModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$log', '$uibModalInstance', 'filterName', 'minDate', 'maxDate', function($scope, $rootScope, $log, $uibModalInstance, filterName, minDate, maxDate) {

    var ctrl = this;

    console.log('filter name', filterName);
    console.log('min date', minDate, 'max date', maxDate);

    ctrl.title = 'Select Dates ' + filterName + '...';
    ctrl.minDate = minDate;
    ctrl.maxDate = maxDate;
    ctrl.customDateFilterForm;

    ctrl.filterDate = (filterName.indexOf('From') !== -1) ? angular.copy(ctrl.minDate) : angular.copy(ctrl.maxDate);

    function setDateToStartOfDay(date) {
      return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
    }

    function setDateToEndOfDay(date) {
      return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);
    }

    ctrl.filterDateChanged = function () {
      ctrl.filterDate = (filterName.indexOf('From') !== -1) ? setDateToStartOfDay(ctrl.filterDate) : setDateToEndOfDay(ctrl.filterDate);
      $log.log('new filter date', ctrl.filterDate);
    };

    ctrl.setFilterDate = function(date) {
      $uibModalInstance.close(date);
    };

    ctrl.cancelDateFilter = function() {
      $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
    };

}])

.directive('customGridDateFilterHeader', function() {
  return {
    template: '<button class="btn btn-default date-time-filter-buttons" style="width:90%;padding:inherit;" ng-click="openDatePicker(colFilter)">{{ colFilter.name }}</button><div role="button" class="ui-grid-filter-button-select cancel-custom-date-range-filter-button ng-scope" ng-click="removeFilter(colFilter, $index)" ng-if="!colFilter.disableCancelFilterButton" ng-disabled="colFilter.term === undefined || colFilter.term === null || colFilter.term === \'\'" ng-show="colFilter.term !== undefined &amp;&amp; colFilter.term != null" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" style=""><i class="ui-grid-icon-cancel cancel-custom-date-range-filter" ui-grid-one-bind-aria-label="aria.removeFilter" aria-label="Remove Filter">&nbsp;</i></div>',
    controller: 'gridDatePickerFilterCtrl'
  };
})
;
```

picker html

```
  <div class="modal-content col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">

    <div class="modal-header">
      <p class="modal-title well custom-date-filter-header">
        <span class="custom-date-filter-title-text">
          {{ custom.title }}
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="row modal-body custom-date-filter-container-row">

      <form name="custom.customDateFilterForm"
            ng-submit="custom.setFilterDate(custom.filterDate)"
            no-validation>

        <div class="row custom-filter-date-input-row">

          <div class="well col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 custom-date-filter-input">

            <uib-datepicker ng-model="custom.filterDate" 
                min-date="custom.minDate" 
                max-date="custom.maxDate"
                ng-change="custom.filterDateChanged()"
                class="well well-sm">
            </uib-datepicker>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row modal-footer custom-date-filter-submit-buttons-row">

          <div class="custom-date-filter-submit-buttons-div col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg custom-date-filter-submit-button"
                    type="submit">
              Apply
            </button>

            <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-warning btn-lg custom-date-filter-cancel-button"
                    ng-click="custom.cancelDateFilter()">
              Cancel
            </button>

          </div>

        </div>

      </form>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uibDatepicker` directive has been modified since [1.3.3 version](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/1.3.3/src/datepicker/datepicker.js) and now it includes `restrict` option:

```
restrict: 'A'
```

So, once migrated to [2.2.0 version](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/2.2.0/src/datepicker/datepicker.js) the date picker  should be modified as well since the directive is *restricted to attribute name*

Replace the declaration:

```
 <uib-datepicker ng-model="custom.filterDate" 
           min-date="custom.minDate" 
           max-date="custom.maxDate"
           ng-change="custom.filterDateChanged()"
           class="well well-sm">
  </uib-datepicker>
```

with

```
<div uib-datepicker ng-model="custom.filterDate" 
         min-date="custom.minDate" 
         max-date="custom.maxDate"
         ng-change="custom.filterDateChanged()"
         class="well well-sm"
 </div>
```

[**Updated** plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CqtLOf9wgnpeCId7Exv4?p=preview)

Comment: You are the MAN! Thanks you for your help and notice, I've already broke my head trying to resolve it.